# Codeigniter form_open not submitting

Tags: codeigniter-2

I've got the following simple search page. 3 fields (one with fixed value) and submit button. When I click submit nothing happens at all. not even reload or anything. the button does nothing. Ignore the arabic in there, I have a feeling it got to do with arrangements of divs or placement of form_open.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>منزلي</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>support/css/main.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        منزلي       
    </div>
        <ul id="list-nav">
            <li><a href="#">للإتصال بنا </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">عن الموقع</a></li>
            <li><a href="/home/index.php/property/load_sale_property">منازل للبيع</a></li>
             <li><a href="/home/index.php/property/load_rent_property">منازل للإيجار</a></li>
             <li><a href="/home/index.php/property/">الرئيسية</a></li>

        </ul>
</div>

<? 
    $this->load->helper('form');

form_open('search/search_properties'); ?>

<div id="center">

    المدينة: 
    <select name="city">
      <option>الخبر</option>
      <option>الدمام</option>
      <option>الظهران</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

Type: <input type="text" value="flat" name="propertyType"/> <br><br>

    حدود السعر:
    <select name="range">
      <option> &lt;20000 </option>
      <option>20000-30000</option>
      <option>30000-40000</option>
      <option>40000-50000</option>
      <option> >500000 </option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="بحث"/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>2012 منزلي &copy;</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

thanks all for support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<? 
    $this->load->helper('form');

form_open('search/search_properties'); ?>
```

should be

```
<? 
    $this->load->helper('form');

echo form_open('search/search_properties'); ?>
```